# Dificuldade com Select

Tags: sql, pl-sql

Quero fazer uma consulta de 1 tabela que possui os registros:

```
Predio |  Local | Produto | FIFO

P01    |  WH01  |  Maçã   | 21/02/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Maçã   | 22/02/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Maçã   | 23/02/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Maçã   | 28/02/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Maçã   | 01/03/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 10/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 11/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 12/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 14/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 15/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 28/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 29/10/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Manga  | 05/11/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Manga  | 08/11/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Abacaxi| 01/12/17

P01    |  WH01  |  Abacaxi| 10/12/17
```

Onde por prédio e local, a quantidade maxima de produtos são 3, o que eu queria era descartar a coluna FIFO para não trazer mais que 1 resultado dos produtos.

Tentei a Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

Predio,
Local,
Produto,
count(Produto) Qnt_de_PNs 

FROM

Controle_Prod_P_Local_E_Predio

WHERE

  Local BETWEEN ('LOCA"')
            AND ('LOCA_FINAL')   

  AND Predio BETWEEN ('Predio')
                 AND ('Predio_FINAL')
  AND Qnt_de_PNs > 3


GROUP BY Predio, Local, Produto
```

Resultado:

```
Predio |  Local | Produto | Qnt_de_PNs

P01    |  WH01  |  Maçã   | 5

P01    |  WH01  |  Pera   | 7
```

Porém sabemos que existem 4 produtos (Maçã, Pera, Manga e Abacaxi), o que eu preciso e que o campo Qnt_de_PNs me traga o resultado de 4.
Isso ocorre, pois o resultado do count se baseia nos registros com FIFO.

Conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Não consegui entender a necessidade

Comment: `Qnt_de_PNs` deve mostrar 4 em todas as linhas?

Comment: Os meus locais não podem ter mais que 3 produtos diferentes. Precisava buscar apenas os locais com mais de 3 produtos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o distinct na função:

```
SELECT 

Predio,
Local,
Produto,
count(DISTINCT Produto) Qnt_de_PNs 

FROM

Controle_Prod_P_Local_E_Predio

WHERE

  Local BETWEEN ('LOCA"')
            AND ('LOCA_FINAL')   

  AND Predio BETWEEN ('Predio')
                 AND ('Predio_FINAL')
  AND Qnt_de_PNs > 3


GROUP BY Predio, Local, Produto
```

Comment: eu nem verifiquei o resto da query... considerei que a sintaxe que ele postou estava correta. Mas posso verificar depois isso

Comment: Rovann, Obrigado! Com o distinct no count todas as linhas ficaram com 1 no campo Qnt_de_PNs. Depois fiz um SUM utilizando uma sub query e consegui o resultado que precisava.

Comment: @JAN tenta colocar isso no SQLFiddle, acho que tem como melhorar.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa retirar do seu where a condição **Qnt_de_PNs > 3**. Desse modo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

Predio,
Local,
Produto,
count(Produto) Qnt_de_PNs 

FROM

Controle_Prod_P_Local_E_Predio

WHERE

  Local BETWEEN ('LOCA"')
        AND ('LOCA_FINAL')   

  AND Predio BETWEEN ('Predio')
             AND ('Predio_FINAL')


GROUP BY Predio, Local, Produto
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, porém não é bem isso. Gostaria de saber quais os local com mais de 3 produtos, pois por padrão só deixaremos 3 por cada local. E efetuarei uma pesquisa em range, por isso queria filtrar o máximo possível